# string is missing the last 2 characters when writing to a CSV file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file that I needed to manipulate, manipulating it went fine, until it writes to a CSV file then it is missing the final characters of the string. I have no idea why because when I loop through the list of strings that it shows the last 2 characters, but when I open up the CSV file the last 2 characters are not there.

The CSV file that I am manipulating looks like..

```
FirstName, Phone, Date, Appointment Time
dan, 123-456-7890, 12/1/2014, 1030
mary, 123-456-7890, 12/2/2014, 100
```

So, I modified it to look like this

```
FirstName, Phone, Date, Appointment Time
dan, 123-456-7890, 12/1/2014 10:30 am
mary, 123-456-7890, 12/2/2014 1:00 pm
```

But when it writes the CSV file, the am/pm is left out.

The code is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
string[] readData = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\TestArea\Data extraction.csv");

List<string> finishedData = new List<string>(readData);
finishedData.RemoveAt(0);

List<string> allData = new List<string>();

foreach (var a in finishedData)
{
    int lastIndex;
    lastIndex = a.LastIndexOf(',');

    string unformattedTime = a.Substring(lastIndex + 1);

    string formatTime = string.Empty;

    if (unformattedTime.Length < 4)
    {
        string hour = Convert.ToString(unformattedTime).Substring(0, 1);
        string minute = Convert.ToString(unformattedTime).Substring(1, 2);
        formatTime = hour + ":" + minute;
    }
    else
    {
        string hour = Convert.ToString(unformattedTime).Substring(0, 2);
        string minute = Convert.ToString(unformattedTime).Substring(2, 2);
        formatTime = hour + ":" + minute;
    }

    string finishedLine = a.Remove(lastIndex) + " " + DateTime.Parse(formatTime).ToShortTimeString().ToLower();

    //Console.WriteLine(finishedLine);
    allData.Add(finishedLine);
}
foreach (String s in allData)
    Console.WriteLine(s);

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\PIA\Test.csv", allData);
Console.ReadLine();
```

}

Comment: If `100` is 1pm whats 1am? - There is no am/pm info in the input so you will need to decide (if its possible) when you build your `formatTime` string and stick it on the end

Comment: 0100...The times are in military time, so I changed it around so its normal time.

Comment: How are you opening the CSV file?  It should be in a text editor (e.g. Notepad) not a spreadsheet (e.g. Excel)

Comment: @JoelFan, I open up the sheet and its opened with excel.

Comment: Right click --> Open With --> Notepad   --or--   Start notepad --> File --> Open --> Choose your file

Comment: @AlexK., I understand what you are saying but when I iterate through the list the am and pm is there, but disappears when written to a CSV. It needs to be a CSV because its for a phone system.

Comment: @JoelFan, needs to open as a csv file. The phone system requires it to be that way

Comment: You are not testing your program properly...  it's fine if it's a CSV file but you're not seeing what's really in the file if you open it in Excel... you need to open it in Notepad to tell what's really going on

Comment: @JoelFan, I just did as you suggested and it shows up properly in NotePad. So, since it looks right in notepad, how do I get it to look right in the CSV? I have to save it as a CSV file

Comment: @Chris You need to get it in a format that Excel will recognize as a date. By the way, I think you're discovering some of the limitations of the CSV file approach. If your goal is actually to generate a file that can be opened in Excel, then you should build an actual `.xlsx` file using a library such as [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854(v=office.15).aspx) or [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @mason, I don't think that I need Excel to recognize it as datetime. I don't think it matters because the phone system will load the CSV file and read it from there. I have an idea...

Comment: My idea didn't work, I decided to cast the finishedline as a string, but when excel looks at it it keeps looking at it as a DateTime

Comment: @Chris Is the goal to view it in Excel? Then you'll need to make sure it is in a format that Excel recognizes as a date. Is your goal to load it into a 3rd party system? Then check the documentation for that system to see what format it expects the data in.

Comment: @mason, its for a third party system. I did look at the documentation and how I have it in the text file is the way its supposed to be. The third party system is voicent. And it insists that it be a CSV file

Comment: @Chris Then I'm afraid I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63427/discussion-between-chris-and-mason).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your file is going to be used by a computer system, it doesn't matter that the data doesn't look quite right in Excel. It only matters that the actual contents of the file are in the format that the system is expecting.

Excel can obscure the underlying format, because it tries to guess at what the data type is and it tries to guess what format it should display the datatype in.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies probably in `DateTime.Parse`. You need to pass `IFormatProvider` as a second argument.